# Woocommerce PDF Invoice shows wrong characters, charset UTF8

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, character-encoding, woocommerce

I have a Danish website that contains characters like ÆØÅ. This works fine in emails and everywhere on the site. When a customer makes a purchase they receive an email with a PDF of the order. This PDF shows the characters correct in the hard coded text but in the text of the product, the characters are not shown correctly.

My htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
php_value default_charset "utf-8"
# END WordPress
```

My config file looks like this:

```
/* MySQL settings */
define( 'DB_NAME',     '------' );
define( 'DB_USER',     '------' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '------' );
define( 'DB_HOST',     '------' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET',  'utf8' );
```

The designers of the web page say that it works fine on their test server, but they are not able to make it work on the server from my host (UnoEuro). I have contacted my host who says that it has something to do with the setup of the htaccess.

Comment: Have you contacted WooThemes support?

Comment: I dont have the license (order number) for the woocommerce since the website has been created by designers who have made the purchase. So I  cant create a ticket on their forum. I was hoping that someone else in there have experience same issue.